# What is the best way to checkpoint node parameters for rosbag MCAP format?

Tags: ros2, mcap

I am logging data in [MCAP format](https://mcap.dev/) using `ros2 bag record -s mcap --all` which saves a `.mcap` file with all my logged data as well as a `metadata.yaml` file with some info about what is stored in the `.mcap` file.

I would like to "checkpoint" my system when I save the data by somehow saving all the ROS parameters along with these files that come from `ros2 bag record`. However, in ROS2 there's no longer a global parameter server and each node has a way of interacting with its own local parameters (see [About parameters in ROS 2](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Concepts/About-ROS-2-Parameters.html)). Is there a standard way to save all ROS parameters from all nodes so that I could have this info in my logs?

I'm about to work on a script to hack such behavior together, and would like to know if I'm wasting my time, that maybe there is already a reasonable solution to this problem that I'm unaware of. Thanks!

Comment: There's no standard way of doing this yet, but MCAP's Metadata and Attachment records could be appropriate places to put this information. Try `mcap help add` to see commands you can use to add attachments/metadata after a recording is made.